# Usage of FreeRTOS xQueueSelectFromSet and xQueueReceive

Tags: freertos

I am using FreeRTOS v8.2.3 on a PIC32 micro controller. I have a case where I need to post the following 3 events to 3 corresponding queues from an ISR, in order to unblock a task awaiting one of these events at a time -
a) SETUP packet arrival
b) Transfer completed event 1
c) Transfer completed event 2

My exection sequence and requirement are as follows:

Case 1 (execution is blocked for an event at point_1):
As SETUP arrives while waiting at point_1 of execution -
i) the waiting task should be unblocked
ii)Setup received from queue and processed

Some code is processed and reaches point_2

Case 2 (execution is blocked for an event at point_2):
If any one of SETUP or transfer complete events occur at point_2 -
i) unblock the wait
ii) receive transfer_complete_1 or transfer_complete_2 event from queue to carry out some additional transfers and loop at point_2
iii)if it was a Setup queue event, do not receive, but go to point_1

The code does not seem to work when I try to use xQueueReceive and xQueueSelectFromSet on the Setup queue even when one of them is used at point_1 and the other used at point_2.
But seems to work fine if I use xQueueSelectFromSet at both the places and verify the queuset member handle that caused the event to proceed further.

Given the requirement above, the problem with using xQueueSelectFromSet at both the places is that
- the xQueueSelectFromSet call will be placed back to back, first on a Setup event at point_2 and then immediately on point_1 which is not intentional
- the xQueueSelectFromSet call at point_1 is also not desired

Hence can anyone please explain whether and how to use both a queueset and queuereceive on the same queue? If not possible how do we typically implement the above requirement in FreeRTOS?

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of a question asked on the FreeRTOS support forum, so below is a duplicate of the answer I gave there:

I don't fully understand your usage scenario, but some points which may help.

1) If a queue is a member of a queue set, then the queue can only be read after its handle has been returned from the queue set. Further, if a queue's handle is returned from a queue set then the item must be read from the queue. If either of these requirements are not met then the state of the queue set will not match that of the queues in the set.

2) If the same task is reading from the multiple queues then it is probably not necessary to use a queue set at all. See the "alternatives to using queue sets" section on the following page: http://www.freertos.org/Pend-on-multiple-rtos-objects.html

Comment: Thanks, Richard, for the pointers. I guess may need a revisit on the queueset alternative with respect to my use cases.